# change text of "return-reason_id" in opencart

Tags: jquery, opencart

Where to find "text/content" of "div class="return-reason_id" in my opencart files?
Want to change text in general.
See link: http://bionatura.noez.in/bionatura/index.php?route=account/return/insert

e.g. change "Dean on Arrival"; can`t find page (.css?, .php.?etc)  to change it!

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done from the backend:

> admin --> system --> localization --> returns

No need to change any code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the controller file on `/catalog/controller/account/return.php`. Your controller method is insert method. You can use language files to change your some text on your page. Your language file is `/catalog/language/YOUR_LANGUAGE/account/return.php` for this page. You can search for `Dean on Arrival` and change what you want.

Example from muy language file : `$_['entry_reason'] = 'Reason for Return:';`. if you change this line from language file, `$this->data['entry_reason'] = $this->language->get('entry_reason');` this line affected from controller file and

```
        <div class="return-reason"><span class="required">*</span> <b><?php echo $entry_reason; ?></b><br />
        <table>
          <?php foreach ($return_reasons as $return_reason) { ?>
          <?php if ($return_reason['return_reason_id'] == $return_reason_id) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td width="1"><input type="radio" name="return_reason_id" value="<?php echo $return_reason['return_reason_id']; ?>" id="return-reason-id<?php echo $return_reason['return_reason_id']; ?>" checked="checked" /></td>
            <td><label for="return-reason-id<?php echo $return_reason['return_reason_id']; ?>"><?php echo $return_reason['name']; ?></label></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <tr>
            <td width="1"><input type="radio" name="return_reason_id" value="<?php echo $return_reason['return_reason_id']; ?>" id="return-reason-id<?php echo $return_reason['return_reason_id']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><label for="return-reason-id<?php echo $return_reason['return_reason_id']; ?>"><?php echo $return_reason['name']; ?></label></td>
          </tr>
          <?php  } ?>
          <?php  } ?>
        </table>
        <?php if ($error_reason) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_reason; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
```

these lines will affect on my .tpl file which you can find your template file name from you controller file.

```
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/return_form.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/return_form.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/account/return_form.tpl';
    }
```

For default return.php template file is `default/template/account/return_form.tpl`.